# image that fills the entire width of the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the image to fill the entire width of the screen but without removing the `class = "img-fluid d-block"` from the image. The image looks like this:
https://postimg.cc/2qw4GK4q

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j5VZxV2h/Captura-de-pantalla-de-2020-12-09-16-25-58.png" class="img-fluid d-block">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `style="width:100vw;"`

Comment: I made you a snippet

Comment: if @johnSmith's answer doesnt work try doing `width: 100%`

Comment: doesn't work, nor with 'width:100vw' nor wirth 'width: 100%'

Comment: @palanganero for me it works, image is full width with no horizontal scrollbar

Comment: with this image works, but with the original one doesn't. It should be because of the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your main problem is that you're using an older version of bootstrap and I'm not sure if those classes you're using (`img-fluid` and `d-block`) even exist in the old 3.x version

In the below example the only changes needed are to add `vw-100` class to the image and add the `p-0` class to the container div. I stripped out the unused script blocks and such to make it clearer.

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 p-0">
      <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/j5VZxV2h/Captura-de-pantalla-de-2020-12-09-16-25-58.png" class="img-fluid d-block vw-100">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```